# How to limit the access to Lambda base on user by Cognito Lambda authorizer

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

### summery

I'm gonna implement AWS Lambda Authorizer by Cognito.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html
But I'm not sure how to limit the access to api/lambda based on user.

For example,
Cognito user pool has two users: user-1, user-2
And there are two AWS Lambda Function for API : lambda-1, lambda-2
In this senario, I want user-1 to access only to lambda-1 and user-2 to lambda-2

please give me the solution to achieve it.

regards,

Answer (score 1):

If you want fine-grained control, you're better of [using a lambda authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html). This would still allow you to do authentication using Cognito.

In your Lambda function, you can return an IAM policy based on the user that is authenticated and restrict the access to only the API paths that you want them to access. You can then simply put both lambdas behind different paths of your API.